# a method to find the nearest multiple of 2pi

Tags: c#, angle

I need to make an efficient function that matches this footprint:

```
public static double NearestAngle(this double currentAngle, double targetAngle);
```

where the return value is `targetAngle +/- n*2pi`. The return value should minimize the absolute difference between itself and `currentAngle`. How can I do this efficiently in C#? I want to avoid loops as the inputs can be many circles apart.

Comment: Can you be more clear about the return value?

Comment: Why the n in n*2pi ? Aren't you looking for a number in [0..2pi) ?  Or can current or target be > 2pi?

Comment: Can you work in degrees instead of radians?  It's hard to work with irrational numbers in code.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for a number [0..2pi). If my `currentAngle == -6` and `targetAngle == 0` I want to return -2pi.

Comment: Your terminology is confusing - you want the return value to be close to currentAngle, not targetAngle???

Comment: @Brannon That's moving the current angle away from the target angle.  Should it not be moving *towards* the target angle?  If not, what is the point in including the target angle at all?

Comment: I want to move targetAngle toward currentAngle without changing targetAngle (aka, keeping it +/-2pi of its original value).

Comment: You confuse more and more. _without changing_ !=  _keeping it in +/-2pi_

Comment: @Brannon `+/- n*2*pi` is NOT the same as "within +/- 2*pi".  Please take one more stab at editing your question to state eactly what you mean.

Comment: I don't know how to phrase the title any better. The question says exactly what I mean, and it was sufficient to get the correct answer. Ideas for a better title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return targetAngle + Math.Round((currentAngle - targetAngle)/(2*Math.Pi))*2*Math.Pi;
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Why?  The problem is to compute the integer factor k such that targetAngle + k * 2 * pi is as close as possible to currentAngle.  Math.Round is there because of the restriction that k be an integer - it has nothing to do with radians vs degrees, because k is unitless.